# Retrieving the profile image from LinkedIn API response

Tags: linkedin-api

I've gone through the authentication and am receiving the correct data from LinkedIn and receiving a response as shown in this link:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2/profile/profile-picture

However, I'm unsure how to extract the image from this:

```
"displayImage": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D03AQGsitRwG8U8ZQ",
```

Do I need to make another request for the image url next?

Answer (score 17):

For anyone else looking, I overlooked there is an `identifier` field like so with a url:

```js
"identifiers": [
 {
  "identifier": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D03AQGsitRwG8U8ZQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100/0?e=1526940000&v=alpha&t=12345",
  "file": "urn:li:digitalmediaFile:     (urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D03AQGsitRwG8U8ZQ,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100,0)",
    "index": 0,
    "mediaType": "image/jpeg",
    "identifierExpiresInSeconds": 1526940000
}
```

To get the above response in ruby I'm doing the following:

```js
url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))'
res = RestClient.get(url, Authorization: "Bearer #{access_token}")
```

Comment: How did you construct call to API to retrieve this output? can you show example with fake params? Thanks!

Comment: In ruby I am doing the following:

`url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))'`


`res = RestClient.get(url, Authorization: "Bearer #{access_token}") `

Comment: Hello, are you using curl? How do you get the identifier item? I having trouble getting the object because of 'displayImage~'

Comment: @bumbumpaw Yes, were you able to get it?

In Ruby I'm using:
```
require 'rest-client'

url = response['profilePicture']['displayImage~']['elements'][3]['identifiers'][0]['identifier']

RestClient.get(url)
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a higher resolution of the profile image? As the `identifier` field provides a 100x100 image

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
 url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,emailAddress,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))&oauth2_access_token=' + access_token
```